# Simultaneous use of plot and inputdlg box in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do some automation with a function in MATLAB.

I plot a graph and then from that plot I want the user to read off 2 values and enter them into some inputdlg boxes.

When the inputdlg appears I can't access the plot to zoom in on the values I want.

Is there a way to do this where I can have the graph free to be used while the 2 inputdlgs appear one after another and then the rest of the code continue to run perhaps on the closing of the graph or the second inputdlg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputdlg` creates modal windows, which means that you can't activate it *and* interact with other windows. I'm afraid that you need to create a figure that will host the input fields that you require.